# Searching a string in a column

Tags: mysql, string

can anyone help me. i have a DB in mysql, and need to search for a string in a particular column.

the field is var char, and contains various serial number, divided by the character  "/".

example

613003593/8876572/TJMC49

the problem is searching in the string. If i use like, it will work most of the times, but not always, because if i do a `like '%13003593%'`  it will return one row, when that is not true, the saved value is 613003593. how can i search, the string.

on the example there are 3 strings divided, and i need to search all of them.

apologies for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of the serial number,

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name
    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(serial_number, '/', 1) = '613003593';
```

For the 2nd part,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(serial_number, '/', 2), '/', -1)='8876572';
```

For the last part,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(serial_number, '/', 3), '/', -1)='TJMC49';
```

Check [How to split and search in comma-separated string in MySQL](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/how-to-split-and-search-in-comma-separated-values-in-mysql/)